# Native C++ SQL Framework

Tags: c++, sql, mysql, oracle, native

I need a high performance framework in native C++ for SQL.
I need it to be able to use MySQL, Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server and provide abstraction
from the lower level problems/idiosyncrasies found in every different syntax required for by DBMS from different vendors. Something like LINQ for C# and VB .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Qt has at least some of what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the [database template library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb/index.html is really awesome.

As a minus - it uses not a very efficient approach at least in a ODBC back end, but for general (not hight load) purposes its purely awesome.